# WAMP Server shows errors when same script runs normally on Linux host

Tags: php, syntax-error, wampserver

This is not the first time I feel WAMP Server is too sensitive on errors. It seems there should be some configurations to decrease it's sensitivity to PHP errors.
I have a script which is run normally on Linux production server (CENTOS 5.8 + Apache + MySQL) but when executed by WAMP server on Windows 7 Ultimate(64bit) the following error is shown:

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...
```

Here I'm not curious about the condition this error occures (I did Google it and find out why it ocurs), my question is why I have experienced many scripts which run normally on production servers while WAMP Server have problem with them. How to down-grade error-level sensitivity of it ?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a script with a syntax error runs fine on a linux server. Are you perhaps talking about warnings?

Comment: @jeroen: Surely it is an error not a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMP Server default value for `short_open_tag` is 0 (off). Editing php.ini solved the problem:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you match the PHP error logging on your CentOS system with your Windows system. Wampserver is just a patched together collection of Apache, MySQL and PHP, and althouh the settings will be different, they can be changed, just as your live server.

Generally you will want to match the live server settings to make sure you don't get any surprises when you go live (though you might want to also switch more verbose warnings/error alerts on while in development, of course). To do this, open the php.ini from the wampserver menu, and match your CentOS one.

Of course, the same can be said about Apache and MySQL and their configurations. Also bear in mind that versions might be different so it would be a good idea to keep those the same, or at least as close as possible to major versions.

Finally, I'd argue that Wampserver wasn't being overly sensitive, but it was showing errors that you have just not noticed yet, and really ought to be fixed, regardless of whether they are hidden away in error or warning log files.